# Magento 2 trying to add column in installschema.php magento 2.3.5 p1

Tags: database, sql, setup-upgrade

I am trying to make the length higher than 255

```
<?php

namespace []\[]\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.1') < 0) {

            $tableName = $installer->getTable('review_comment');
            if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {

                $table = $installer->getConnection()
                    ->newTable($tableName)
                    ->addColumn(
                        'id',
                        Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                        null,
                        array(
                            'identity' => true,
                            'nullable' => false,
                            'primary' => true,
                        ),
                        'ID'
                    )

                    ->addColumn('comment', Table::TYPE_TEXT, '2M', [], 'Comment') //NOW this fixed don't know how 

                    ->addColumn(
                        'enable',
                        Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null,
                        array(
                            'nullable' => false,
                        ),
                        'Enable'
                    )
                    ->addColumn(
                        'creator',
                        Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255,
                        array(
                            'nullable' => false,
                        ),
                        'Creator'
                    )
                    ->addColumn(
                        'created_at',
                        Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                        null,
                        ['nullable' => true],
                        'Created At'
                    )
                    ->addColumn(
                        'updated_at',
                        Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                        null,
                        ['nullable' => true],
                        'Updated At'
                    )
                    ->setComment('Custom');

                $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
            }
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

but I get the following error ->
Syntax error or access violation: 1170 BLOB/TEXT column 'comment' used in key specification without a key length

But this didn't work

```
->addColumn(
    'comment',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    '2M',
    ['nullable' => false],
    'Comment'
)
```

Comment: You can not apply length for a  text field if length greater than 255.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
->addColumn(
    'your_column',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    '2M',
    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0'],
    'Comment'
)
```

Use `declarative schema` for creating a table with Column

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html

If already created `InstallSchema.php` in your module then create `UpgradeSchema.php` for creating and updating a new column in table

Remove Module entry in the `setup_module` table and also remove the `review_comment` table in the database and hit upgrade command and check.

> **InstallSchema.php**

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

/**
 * Class InstallSchema
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @throws \Zend_Db_Exception
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('review_comment')
        )->addColumn(
            'id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'comment',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            '2M',
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Comment'
        )->addColumn(
            'enable',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Enable'
        )->addColumn(
            'creator',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Creator'
        )->addColumn(
            'created_at',
            Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
            'Created At'
        )->addColumn(
            'updated_at',
            Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            ['nullable' => false, 'default' => Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
            'Updated At'
        )->setComment('Custom');
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you...!

Comment: When i run set:up i get error new error Syntax error or access violation: 1101 BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY or JSON column 'comment' can't have a default value

Comment: Have you try above code

Comment: yeah that didn't work for me  but this worked don't know why ->addColumn('comment', Table::TYPE_TEXT, '2M', [], 'Comment')

Comment: Can you show me your schema file ? Please upload in question so will try to solve your problem

Comment: i have updated now

Comment: Please give me some time

Comment: That's fine and thank you I have commented on the code the part is working now but not sure why the other didn't work

Comment: hey check I have updated my answer please check and follow above setps. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes!! what was the issue then this worked :)